# How do I split the system partition (C:) in Windows7?

Tags: partitioning

On my new laptop total HD space is 750GB and available total space is 676GB (after OS install) and 632 GB is Free on C:. 
When I use Shrink drive, it only creates/assign 337 GB to new partition and 339 GB to C: (OS one). 
I want to make c: (which has OS) 120 GB and rest of approx 510 GB as new partition for data.

What should I do, as Shrink option don't work. Will any 3rd party tool do this?

Thanks in advance.

(Other posted question do not address this).

Answer (score 4):

you could try gparted

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to defrag c: first and then rinse and repeat shrink drive with the alternate partition values. It's possible that shrink drive works better on defrag hard disks.

Comment: I don't know if the defarg would matter because after defrag there are still files at the start and end of the drive.

Comment: @nhutto: Are you sure? What files?

Comment: depending on what the OS decides per file. files are placed either at the start of the drive or closer to the out side you can use tools like O & O defrag to see a map of your drive and defrag according to sere you want each item place. how every the default windows one just groups you fragments in to group blobs.

Comment: `$MFTMirr` is intentionally placed in the middle or at the end of an NTFS volume.  After the questioner's first shrink operation, it is probably at or near the end of the volume now.  And as nhutto says _making a file's storage contiguous_ is not the same as _relocating it to the start of the volume_.

Comment: It is brand new computer, so defrag will not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use built in tools to resize a system drive - since its in use, and you need to unmount the drive to resize, which naturally, you cannot.

You can either use a livecd - such as the aformentioned gparted (or qtparted), or a third party resize tool (I've had great luck with [easus partition manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/) that will run the resize process on boot.

Comment: Since at least Windows Vista, the boot/system can indeed be shrunk/enlarged using the inbuilt Disk Management tool. Some system files are immovable, though, and limit extent of shrinkage possible.

Answer (score 2):

get [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) installer (you don't need to install it, it's a LiveCD). There is a gparted. It's really easy to use.

Always backup all important data before resizing a partition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok:

- Start.
- TYpe: "Partition disk" and Select the Disk & Partitions Manager
- Right click on your Partition C:
- Select Reduce
- Reduce from the size you want to allocate to other Partitions.
- Right click on empty Space and select "Create New Volume"

Comment: If you read my original post, ..... >>When I use Shrink drive, it only creates/assign 337 GB to new partition and 339 GB to C: (OS one). I want to make c: (which has OS) 120 GB and rest of approx 510 GB as new partition for data. So these steps did not help...